# Pass data from view to block

Tags: redirect, messages, singleton, core-session

I'm trying to pass a message from view to layout by using a model.
This does not work when using `_redirect();`
I know there is a magento core functionality, but I'd like to understand why my custom solution does not work.

```
$status = Mage::getSingleton('custom/statusobject');
$status ->setMessage('Error:' + $message);

//$status ->getMessage(); Works fine

$this->_redirect('*/*/');

public function indexAction()
{
   $status = Mage::getSingleton('custom/statusobject');
   $status ->getMessage(); // does not exists
}
```

**** EDIT ****
This does also not work for session

in controller

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setError('ERROR');
session_write_close();
$this->_redirectUrl('*/*/');
return;
```

In my block

```
$statusobject = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
$message =$statusobject->getMessages()->getItems();

print_r($message); // empty array
```

I dont know why my messages are lost after redirect

Answer (score 1):

You need to **save()** for  carry data.

```
$status = Mage::getSingleton('custom/statusobject');
$status ->setMessage('Error:' + $message);
$status->save();
//$status ->getMessage(); Works fine
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
```

this will works when **message** is field of *custom/statusobject* .

Or better idea to sue `core/session` variable to carry value on new page.

*`Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyMessage('Error:' + $message);`*

**fetch Data on new page using**

*`Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyMessage();`*

Comment: ah okay I saw it does not work in this setup also for core/session.
Okay so I really have to perfom DB action then?
When using core/session I also need to do the save action?

Answer (score 1):

i think solution you need is `register`. that are use in magento to carry data between controller to block or view. because session need to reload the page.

**you can set register**

```
Mage::register('name-of-registry-key', $your-data);
```

**get registry**

```
$var = Mage::registry('name-of-registry-key');
```

Comment: is this more recommended than passing between controller -> model -> block?
I thought this would be a more mvc like approach?

Comment: yes it is mvc approach also it destroy after load page.

Comment: Mage::register('name-of-registry-key', 'foobar'); -> did this in my controller

this in my block 

$var = Mage::registry('name-of-registry-key');

but did not work

Comment: did you echo it echo $var = Mage::registry('name-of-registry-key'); because i use as many time i can't count. so could not find any single problem with this. also use it before the  $this->loadLayout(); in controller

Comment: I used print_r to be sure :)
It works until my redirect  $this->_redirect('custom/formsubmit/'); then it is empty

Comment: yes it empty after the redirect and use echo because you are have a string not array..

Comment: yes but I want to have it also available after redirect :)

Comment: Then you have to use session too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31448/discussion-between-christoph-ha-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: I am on mobile right now can't do chat

Comment: first of all i tell how session work. when you set the value of session you need to reload to get the session values. it is like normal session work.